# Machine crashes when trying to shutdown in Assembly and C

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, osdev

I created an assembly file that shuts down the computer, along with some C code. When I try linking with ld. It worked
Also, here's the code that does that:

```asm
# set flags to 0
.set FLAGS,    0

# set magic number to 0x1BADB002 to identified by bootloader 
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002

# set the checksum
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

# set multiboot enabled
.section .multiboot

# define type to long for each data defined as above
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM


# set the stack bottom 
stackBottom:

# define the maximum size of stack to 512 bytes
.skip 4096


# set the stack top which grows from higher to lower
stackTop:

.section .text
.global _start
.type _start, @function

shutdown:
  mov %ax, 0x1000
  mov %ax, %ss
  mov %sp, 0xf000
  mov %ax, 0x5307
  mov %bx, 0x0001
  mov %cx, 0x0003
  int $0x15

  ret

_start:

  # assign current stack pointer location to stackTop
    mov $stackTop, %esp

  # call the kernel main function
    call kernel_entry
    call shutdown

    cli


# put system in infinite loop
hltLoop:

    hlt
    jmp hltLoop

.size _start, . - _start
```

When I try it in Virtualbox it says this:[image: Running it in Virtualbox]

In QEMU, the machine crashes and reboots.

**Is there a way for me to power off the OS correctly without errors? Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: You can't use `int 0x15` from protected mode that I assume you are in due to the multiboot stuff. The simplest is probably switching back to real mode, assuming you haven't destroyed the IVT and BIOS data area. If you only need this to work in virtualbox there is magic i/o port for that (and other emulators too). See [osdev.org](https://wiki.osdev.org/Shutdown#Emulator-specific_methods)

Comment: I tried it @Jester but it says this: Error: `%al' not allowed with outw

Comment: What's going on with it?

Comment: The `w` in `outw` means _word_. `%al` is a byte. You want `%ax`.

Comment: I just used `asm volatile("outw %0, %1" : : "a"(data), "Nd"(port));`. Where is %al  in here?(sorry, I am not really expreicenced with ASM)

Comment: Presumably your `data` is `char` so the compiler uses `%al`. If you have your assembly file anyway, why use C inline asm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214834/discussion-between-fastdeveloper-and-jester).

Comment: Have you tried using BOCHS?  It has a built-in debugger that should give you more info on a triple fault or other error.  If that VBox "critical error" message is all the information you get, use a better VM / emulator, or attach a debugger to VBox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to do it in Emulator-specific ways. Thanks Jester for helping me out!

Comment: This is very little help to future readers; your answer doesn't say anything about how it's actually done.  It's fine to answer your own question, but only with a real answer, not just a vague hint at how you solved it.  e.g. if anyone else had posted this as an answer to this question, I would have downvoted for sure.  (And so would you, I assume).  Since it's your own question, I'll be generous and not downvote right away.